# I use ubuntu studio 22.04. JACK crashes when some application attempts to access audio

Tags: jack

I am an experienced user of ubuntu studio. I maintain about 25 machines with it installed. I have 22.04. On one machine only, JACK crashes when an application attempts access. aplay for the specified audio card works fine. Here is a log from an attempt using qjackctl to start JACK:

> quote
> Jack: JackRequest::GetUUIDByClient
> Cannot read socket fd = 29 err = Success
> CheckRes error
> JackSocketClientChannel read fail
> Jack: JackClientSocket::Close
> Jack: JackLibClient::ShutDown
> Jack: JackClient::ShutDown
> Jack: JackPosixThread::ThreadHandler : exit
> 18:11:49.026 Notificación de apagado.
> 18:11:49.038 Cliente desactivado.

The failure is independent of pulse bridging or not, and of cpu governor settings.
Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. /etc/security/limits.d/audio.conf increased prio to 99 and activated niceness for audio to -19. I think the irq's for a couple of network cards were muscling out jack.